# Add Specific Map Layout Name to Document Path in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, pdf, file-path, dynamic-text

In ArcGIS Pro (using 2.6.2), the `<dyn type="project" property="path"/>` dynamic text only provides the path of the entire project. It does not include the actual map or layout within that project. I would like to include this so when I export to PDF, another user can know exactly which map the PDF is sourced from. Is there a way to append this information to the file path, using dynamic text or another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is using the   `<dyn type="layout" name="LayoutName" property="name"/>` formatting tag.